# Connecting to Informix with Perl DBI by ip:port

Tags: perl, informix, dbi

I am trying to use `DBI` (with `DBD::Informix`) to connect to Informix given only an ip address and port number. In this context, I can not depend on the sql hosts file on the machine being accurate. Is what I am doing possible?

In the documentation they mention connection strings in the form of `//machine1/dbase` so I gave this a try:

```
DBI->connect("dbi:Informix://10.1.23.232:2232/eris", $user, $pass);
```

but received the following error:

> DBI connect('//10.1.23.232:2232/eris','someuser',...) failed: SQL: -1804: Invalid database environment. at tools/check_informix.pl line 63

What is the correct approach to connecting to an Informix server knowing only a port and ip address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation using `//machine/dbase` is primarily for use with Informix Standard Engine, SE (and I believe the `:port` notation would not be recognized even then; I'd have to research to find out which port is used, but it is likely 1525 or 1526).  AFAIK, it does not work with Informix Dynamic Server, IDS.  You need to create an entry in the sqlhosts file for a server name, which specifies the machine (raw I/P address OK) and the port (raw port number OK), such as:

```
myremoteserver   olsoctcp   10.1.23.232   2232
```

You would then specify the connection string as:

```
eris@myremoteserver
```

You can specify any file as the sqlhosts file with the INFORMIXSQLHOSTS variable.  The server name you specify in the sqlhosts file must match the actual server name on the host with I/P address 10.1.23.232 that is listening on port 2232.

Comment: Thanks! I submit to the need to accept a server name. I create a temporary hosts file (using File::Temp) and change INFORMIXSQLHOSTS to point to it. Is there any way I can avoid fiddling with environmental variables or writing to the file system?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for DBD::Informix your approach looks ok except the pod for DBD::Informix just says //machine1/dbase and does not mention the port. Perhaps you forgot to set INFORMIXDIR in your environment. See [CONNECTING TO A DATABASE](http://search.cpan.org/~johnl/DBD-Informix-2011.0612/Informix.pm#CONNECTING_TO_A_DATABASE).

Comment: You get different error messages if INFORMIXDIR is not set, and DBD::Informix records the setting of $INFORMIXDIR at compile time and uses that at run time if the environment variable is not set.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Leffler described, knowing the server name (and the REAL server name) is unavoidable. Here is a proof of concept script that generates and uses its own sqlhosts file, given the required information.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;

# core
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);

# CPAN
use DBI;

die "Usage: $0 host port server database user password\n" if (@ARGV != 6);
my ($host, $port, $server, $database, $user, $password) = @ARGV;

my ($handle, $path) = tempfile("sqlhosts_$server\_XXXXX");

print $handle "$server onsoctcp $host $port\n";

close($handle);

my $sqlhosts = File::Spec->rel2abs($path);

$ENV{'INFORMIXSQLHOSTS'} = $sqlhosts;
$ENV{'INFORMIXSERVER'}   = $server;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Informix:$database\@$server", $user, $password);

say 'Yay! It worked!';

$dbh->disconnect();

unlink $sqlhosts;
```